# Tensorflow Op Naming for Consecutive Runs in Interactive IPython terminal

Tags: python, ipython, tensorflow

I've noticed that on subsequent runs of a Tensorflow script, your graph Ops get numbered names for example:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.l2_loss(y - pred), name="l2_loss")
```

would get the names:

```
l2_loss
l2_loss_1
l2_loss_2
...
l2_loss_N
```

as you continue to make the same runs in the same IPython session. This wouldn't be so annoying, except that later in scripts when you want to save a summary:

```
x_sample, y_sample = get_sample(X, Y)
feed = {x: x_batch, y: y_batch}
trainer.run(feed_dict=feed)
summary_str = summary_op.eval(feed_dict=feed)
```

you'll get the following failure:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x_input' with dtype float ....
```

Is there a way to (at the top of a script or something) to void all these old, out-of-date Op definitions and use the current run and correctly obey the `name=...` imperative when creating variables, placeholders, and constants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to add `tf.reset_default_graph()` to the beginning of the script where you set up the graph. That deletes all existing tensors, variables and operations from the default graph. This way previous executions of the script will not interfere.

I am not sure, though, if the error message you get has anything to do with that. Are you sure you are not just forgetting to feed a value for placeholder `x_input`? You are feeding for placeholder `x`, should that maybe be `x_input`?

Comment: No I copied that code from elsewhere, I'll edit the question. Great, the  `tf.reset_default_graph()` seems to work if I add just before I create a session. I do get a funny warning, though: `Exception AssertionError: AssertionError("Nesting violated for default stack of <type 'weakref'> objects",) in <bound method InteractiveSession.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.InteractiveSession object at 0x115099210>> ignored`, any idea what that's about?

Answer (score 8):

To your follow-up question, you might be getting the `AssertionError` due to redefining your interactive session.

```
sess = InteractiveSession()
sess = InteractiveSession()
Exception AssertionError: AssertionError("Nesting violated for default stack of <type 'weakref'> objects") in ...
```

You can avoid this by closing the session first, `sess.close()`.